# Test module can't resolve module being tested [Angular4, Karma, Jasmine]

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, karma-runner

I have a small TypeScript app created as a demo project. It is using Angular 4, Karma, Webpack 2 and Jasmine.

The app builds successfully and I can run it in a browser.

The tests do not work, when I run `karma start` in the command line, I see a message like this:

> ERROR in ./app/welcome/app.welcome.spec.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.welcome' in 'D:\ng-ts-demo\app\welcome'
>   @ ./app/welcome/app.welcome.spec.ts 4:20-44
>   @ ./app .spec.ts
>   @ ./app/test-main.ts

The weird thing is, the app.welcome.ts file is in the same directory as app.welcome.spec.ts but still it cannot find it! From the message it appears that the problem is caused by the test-main.ts file not loading the *.ts files, only the *.spec.ts files.

I've followed the official Angular 4/Webpack guide [here](https://angular.io/guide/webpack) and I do not seem to be missing anything critical.

Here is my test-main.ts file:

```
Error['stackTraceLimit'] = Infinity;

import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';

import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

let appContext = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts/); // is this line the problem?

appContext.keys().forEach(appContext);

TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
```

Here is my Karma.conf.js file:

```
'use strict';

const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        files: [
            { pattern: './app/test-main.ts' }
        ],
        exclude: [],
        preprocessors: {
            './app/test-main.ts': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
        },
        reporters: ['progress'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: false,
        browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
        customLaunchers: {
            ChromeHeadless: {
                base: 'Chrome',
                flags: [
                  '--headless',
                  '--remote-debugging-port=9222',
                  '--disable-gpu',
                  '--disable-plugins',
                  '--window-size=0,0',
                  '--window-position=-9999,0'
                ],
            },
        },
        singleRun: true,
        concurrency: Infinity,
        webpack: {
            module: {
                rules: [{
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                            options: {
                                configFileName: './tsconfig.json'
                            }
                        },
                        'angular2-template-loader'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            devtool: 'inline-source-map',
            plugins: [
                new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/, './app')
            ]
        },
        webpackMiddleware: {
            stats: 'errors-only'
        },
        webpackServer: {
            noInfo: true
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the app.welcome.spec.ts file:

```
import { TestBed }            from '@angular/core/testing';
import { WelcomeComponent }   from './app.welcome';

describe('The Welcome component', function () {

    let component: WelcomeComponent;

    beforeEach(function() {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [WelcomeComponent]
        });

        let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WelcomeComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should be a component', function() {
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should have a welcome message', function () {
        expect(component.welcomeMessage).toEqual('Welcome to TypeScript!');
    });

});
```

And here is the app.welcome.ts module (which is in the same folder as the spec file, but mysteriously cannot be found):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>{{welcomeMessage}}</h1>',
})

export class WelcomeComponent {
    welcomeMessage = 'Welcome to TypeScript!';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a number of issues to overcome in getting this working. The first fix was to add a resolve config to the `webpack` config within karma.conf.js:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
},
```

This solved the problem of my test files not being able to import the files they were testing.

This then lead to the second problem - the test files themselves were not being executed (I could see `Executed 0 of 0 ERROR` in the command line output when running the test. Debugging the test (by setting `singleRun` to `false` and changing browser from `ChromeHeadless` to regular `Chrome` showed an error in the console:

> Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:9876/base/test-main.ts' because its MIME type ('video/mp2t') is not executable.

This is a new issue affecting Chrome 55+ and there is a slightly hacky fix that is needed for now; I had to add this to the karma.conf.js file (not in the `webpack` config section though):

```
mime: {
    'text/x-typescript': ['ts']
},
```

This tip was picked up in [this](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/karma-webpack/issues/188) issue. Finally now the tests are running :)

Now to get coverage working also...